# Working with tiered data

Tags: categorical-data, ordinal-data, medicine

I have data on a sample of individuals infected with a disease, which has several serovars (distinct variations of the bacteria - e.g., Bratislava, Hardio, Grippo). An infected individual can test positive for multiple serovars, and it is common practice to (a) identify which serovar is most prevalent for each case use that as the (categorical) response variable (b) determine whether the case is infected (i.e., tests positive for at least one serovar) and use that as the (binary categorical) response variable, or (c) count the number of different serovars the case tested positive for and use that as the (quantitative) response variable.

**But is there a way to somehow use the relative ranking (or even quantitative variations between serovars) for each person as the response variable in something like linear regression or a structural equation model?** The goal of the research is to use something like regression or structural equation models to evaluate the effects of various environmental risk factors on these infections, so a single (but perhaps multifaceted) response variable would be ideal.

A example (with fewer variables and cases) is below:

| id | Bratislava | Hardio | Grippo | TopSerovar | Infected | CountSerovar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.8 | 1.45 | 0 | Bratislava | YES | 2 |
| 2 | 8.9 | 2.3 | 9.8 | Grippo | YES | 3 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | NA | NO | 0 |

For each person, the measurement could essentially be a string of which serovars they tested positive for, and in what order (e.g., Case 1: Bratislava-Hardio). Alternatively, it could be a set of number indicating the magnitude of each serovar (e.g., Case 1: 2.8, 1.45, 0)

My first thought was just to use all the serovars as independent response variables at the same time in a multivariate regression framework, but since there is a fair amount of correlation between them (a person who tests positive for one serovar is more likely to test positive for a second), I'm assuming it would require some dependence structure among the response variables.

My hope is that there exists a more elegant solution!

Comment: Do you have quantitative measures on the serovars? Maybe use some measure of [tag:diversity], or the quantitative measures directly ...

Comment: Yes, there are quantitative measures for each serovar, which can be used to either identify which one is most present or to rank them. But is there a way to fold it into a single variable (that accounts for the order)?

Comment: What is the final goal of the analysis? I think you must give some more details, including sample sizes (and number of patients.) There are many possibilities, including a multivariate logistic regression ...

Comment: The final goal is to evaluate which demographic and environmental risk factors best predict infection among ~1500 sampled individuals. A multivariate approach could work, but I'm hoping to link the multiple response variables together in some coherent manner (not just as independent responses).